# Is there an alternative way to print repeating characters in java?

Tags: java

I am trying to display this:

```
Hamburger................$10.00
Chicken Sandwich....$12.00
```

However, the only way I know to do it is to type all characters.

```
System.out.println("Hamburger................$10.00");<br>
System.out.println("Chicken Sandwich....$12.00");
```

I just want to ask if there's an easy way to type the code without repetitively typing '.' ?

Comment: If you're only doing 5 or 10 items, there's not really a faster way. If you are doing lots, I would take for instance your original string `Hamburger`, get its length, subtract that length from a fixed number like 20, then use a loop to build a string of dots of that length. You would then need to do this for each of your food items using an array of strings. Good luck!

Comment: Your display output is not a fixed-width font, which is why your `.` padding is not a consistent length. There is nothing you can do in pure Java for that, without information about the font in use.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a method to print the entire line, text, dots and amount.

```
static void itemLine( int width, String text, double value ){
  DecimalFormat myFormatter = new DecimalFormat("$###,##0.00");
  String numstr = myFormatter.format(value);
  int dots = width - text.length() - numstr.length();
  System.out.print( text );
  for( int i = 0; i < dots; ++i ) System.out.print( '.' );
  System.out.println( numstr );
}
```

Saves you the trouble of counting the number of times the dots are required.

Answer (score 0):

You could print from a for-loop (`System.out.print` so that all your output will be on the same line). Or, as I prefer, you can make a static method:

```
public static String repeat(String val, int times){
  String returnVal = val;
  for(int i = 1; i < times; i++)
    returnVal += val;
  return returnVal;
}
```

This way, you can change your code to:

```
System.out.println("Hamburger" + repeat(".",18) + "$10.00");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
new String(Collections.nCopies(18, '.').toArray(new char[18]));
```